# MySQL Tables Multiple Records Appearing Over Time

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working with a MySQL table through MySQL Workbench. Currently, many of my tables are appearing more than once with some appearing 10+ times. It is not messing anything up with my application or when I run a query on any of these tables, but something that I feel should be fixed. Haven't been able to find anything and just assuming this is a quick fix.

[MySQL Table List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjT0v.png)

Currently running MySQL Workbench 8.0.23 build 365764 SE (64 bits), MySQL Azure Database System.

Also, is there any reason that this would be happening? I have a variety of php files set up to read/write data, my hunch is that some lines of code may be creating duplicates that I need to nail down, is there any specific SQL syntax that would be creating these duplicates (other than CREATE TABLE..., I do not have anything of that nature set to run).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe related to this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149693/duplicate-table-names-after-restoring-a-backup

Comment: the current version is 8.0.25 and more to come, update it, there where a lot of strange bugs